# How to structure the table of contents with arabic and roman numbers?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, links

What I want to achieve is, that the first few sections and included page numbers of my document should be in `roman` and the rest of the document in `arabic` numbers.

Like this:

I   ....

II  ....

1   ....

2   ....

3   ....

Now this works fine, the page numbers and sections are numbered as I want them to. But I have the following problem: if I click the first section of my "arabic section" in the table of contents it jumps to the first "roman section". This happens for the amount of "roman sections". If I click on the third "arabic section" it's fine.

I just want a jump to the right section, if I click it in the table of contents.

This is what I have:

```
 \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, ngerman, oneside, bibtotoc, liststotoc, bibtotocnumbered, toctotoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\newcommand{\sectionnumbering}[1]{% 
  \setcounter{section}{0}% 
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\csname #1\endcsname{section}}}

\begin{document}
    \section{Deckblatt}
    ...

    \pagenumbering{roman} 
    \sectionnumbering{Roman}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \section{Erklaerung}

    \section{Sperrvermerk}  

    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \listoffigures
    \clearpage

    \pagenumbering{arabic} 
    \sectionnumbering{arabic}

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection{} #1}{}}

    \section{KapitelEinleitung}
    \section{...}
\end{document}
```

I tried some suggested solutions using `\newcounter{}` and `\setcounter{}{}`, but with no success.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Where is `\sectionnumbering` from? All the files from `\include`... are unavailable to users here

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I updated the question, with all necessary packages.

Comment: I assume you forgot to include hyperref.  Where does Abbildungsverzeichnis come from?  It is listed in the toc as a section* (or phantomsection).

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that hyperref is using the section number instead of the stc counter.

Comment: @JohnKormylo "Abbildungsverzeichnis" is the german translation of \listoffigures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this behaviour as described by the OP is the resetting of section counters, thus confusing `hyperref`. Using `hypertexnames=false` as an option to `hyperref` will generate unique page anchor link names.

```
 \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, ngerman, oneside, bibtotoc, liststotoc, bibtotocnumbered, toctotoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[unicode,hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\PrerenderUnicode{ä}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\newcommand{\sectionnumbering}[1]{% 
  \setcounter{section}{0}% 
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\csname #1\endcsname{section}}%
}%

\begin{document}
\section{Deckblatt}

\pagenumbering{roman} 
\sectionnumbering{Roman}
\pagestyle{empty}
\section{Erklärung}
\section{Sperrvermerk}  
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\sectionnumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection{} #1}{}}
\section{KapitelEinleitung}
\section{...}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works but the section numbering goes like this: I.., II..., 3...

Comment: @SteveBenett: I will look later on

Comment: @SteveBenett: I have updated my solution

Answer (score 1):

I had to fool hyperref into thinking you were using chapters.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, ngerman, oneside, bibtotoc, liststotoc, bibtotocnumbered, toctotoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcounter{chapter}% causes hyperref to use chapter numbers
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\newcommand{\sectionnumbering}[1]{% 
  \stepcounter{chapter}% used by hyperref only
  \setcounter{section}{0}% not automatic
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\csname #1\endcsname{section}}}

\begin{document}
    \section{Deckblatt}
    ...

    \pagenumbering{roman} 
    \sectionnumbering{Roman}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \section{Erklaerung}

    \section{Sperrvermerk}  

    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \listoffigures
    \clearpage

    \pagenumbering{arabic} 
    \sectionnumbering{arabic}

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection{} #1}{}}

    \section{KapitelEinleitung}
    \section{...}
 \end{document}
```